# How to correct java.sql.SQLException: Database 'dbname' not found error?

Tags: java, netbeans, derby

I am trying to embed a Derby DB in my application using the following code to connect to the database:

```
                String host = "jdbc:derby:PlayerScores";
                String uName = "user1";
                String uPass = "pass123";

                String driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
                Class.forName(driver);

                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);
```

When I test the application and try save the data, the following message comes up:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Database 'PlayerScores' not found
```

I have checked my libraries and already have the `derby.jar`and the `derbyclient.jar`files in place.

I have checked my database name and it is correct.

How can I try correct this problem?

Comment: How are you running your application?? From the IDE? Are you using Windows or Linux??

Comment: Yes I am running it from the IDE just to test the code before testing it on another computer

Comment: try `String host = "jdbc:derby:PlayerScores;create=true";`

Comment: Have you defined a system directory via the system property 'derby.system.home' and does your database live in that directory?

Comment: @wero I read that statement will create the db, but it's already created. So is that statement still worth trying?

Comment: @kem I did see a few sites talk about this, but none were very clear on how to go about it. How would I define the system directory (basically do I need to locate where the db is being stored)?

Comment: @Osiris93 if you already have created the database go with carlitos answer and specify an absolute path

Comment: @Osiris93 e.g. if the absolute path to your database is '/foo/bar/PlayerScores', then you would set the system property 'derby.system.home' to '/foo/bar' when you run your program

Comment: @Osiris93 docs: https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.0/manuals/develop/develop14.html#HDRDEVELOP846369

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to define an absolute path for your database... Example:

```
String host = "jdbc:derby:/my/database/path/PlayerScores;create=true";
```

See this [link](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/devguide/rdevdvlp22102.html#rdevdvlp22102) for more examples...

Comment: But won't this cause a problem when I try run the application on a different computer with a different file path?

Comment: Yes, so you have to make your application configurable (through commnad line parameters or property files)...